# Changing a complex INNER JOIN query and displaying it with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have this `SQL` query where I make a list of people who paid this month, and who didn't:

```
SELECT  main.* 
FROM    (SELECT    t1.client_name, t1.total_debts, t2.client_id, sum(payment) payments , t2.date_now ,
                    CASE MONTH(t2.date_now)  
                       WHEN MONTH(CURDATE()) THEN 'Paid'
                       ELSE 'Not Paid'
                    END current_month
        FROM client_debts t1  INNER JOIN client_details t2  ON t1.id = t2.client_id 
        GROUP BY t2.client_id) main
WHERE   main.total_debts<> main.payments;
```

So I've got this result:

[image]

As we see in the picture, I have the same client, pays for one item this month, but he didn't pays for the other item, so practically, he came to my store and gave me money, so I need to remove his name from the list as `Not Paid` and keep the row where it said `Paid`.

And how can I run this query in PHP so I can put it inside a table for displaying. [I tried the answer here in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667590/echo-results-of-a-complicated-inner-join-query-with-multiple-tables)

```
    $sql = "SELECT  main.* 
FROM    (SELECT    t1.client_name, t1.total_debts, t2.client_id, sum(payment) payments , t2.date_now ,
                    CASE MONTH(t2.date_now)  
                       WHEN MONTH(CURDATE()) THEN 'Paid'
                       ELSE 'Not Paid'
                    END current_month
        FROM client_debts t1  INNER JOIN client_details t2  ON t1.id = t2.client_id 
        GROUP BY t2.client_id) main
WHERE   main.total_debts<> main.payments;";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $exec = $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Then HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
        <table>
        <?php foreach($res as $row){ ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['t1.client_name']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </table>
        </div>
```

But it keeps telling me:

> Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp\www...

Comment: So in this case what should come in `payment` column for that user. `50`?

Comment: no, just showing the row where he actually paid

Comment: Why does this client have two different client_ids then? And what is this total_debts field?

Comment: those are the ids from client_details, the main ID of the client is in the reference table called client_debts, and here the total debts is for each items he bought in client_details table

Comment: I think there are 2 questions here. 1)" You are saying that the SQL you gave works correctly or do you want to run it in `php` but not able to run it due to give error". And 2) - "You want to change the query to only return `Paid` users hiding the `Not Paid` rows. That means 3 rows from your example" Is that correct?

Comment: yes @Utsav, I need to remove a row that said علي `Not Paid` because he already pays, for another item earlier this month, so he actually came and gave money, by the way, the PHP problem is solved

Comment: i don't see any code that your accessing the index `id`

Comment: so I need to remove for this user the row where it said `not paid`

Comment: @roullie Yes I do. with client_debts.id, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34759781/removing-rows-and-comparing-months/34760161

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL issue can be handled by adding an `and` condition in `where` clause at end. This is assuming that all rows are entitled for that duration of payment. In case the data is spanned across multiple months, then we need another query.

```
SELECT  main.* 
FROM    (SELECT    t1.client_name, t1.total_debts, t2.client_id, sum(payment) payments , t2.date_now ,
                    CASE MONTH(t2.date_now)  
                       WHEN MONTH(CURDATE()) THEN 'Paid'
                       ELSE 'Not Paid'
                    END current_month
        FROM client_debts t1  INNER JOIN client_details t2  ON t1.id = t2.client_id 
        GROUP BY t2.client_id
        ) main
WHERE   main.total_debts<> main.payments
and current_month='Not Paid'
and client_name not in 
(select client_name from main 
where current_month='Paid'
);
```

Comment: Well, it works but when I change it to be show me the list of who didn't Paid by replace `and main.current_month <> 'Not Paid';` to `and main.current_month <> 'Paid';` the client علي is listed, practically, he shouldn't, because, he actually paid for another item earlier this month, and the PHP problem is solved

Comment: replace condition to and main.current_month = 'Paid' and it will work

Comment: Sir, what I want is if a user paid for an item, and didn't paid for another, this month, to only show his name, in list of `Paid`, and the list of `Not Paid` should only include people who didn't paid at all this month for none of items

Comment: If it works for you, then [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer so it could be closed. Thanks.

Comment: Ok got you. Let me come up with query

Comment: No it didn't works yet, what I want is if a user paid for an item, and didn't paid for another, this month, to only show his name, in list of Paid, and the list of Not Paid should only include people who didn't paid at all this month for none of items

Comment: @androidnation Can you please provide sample data that illustrates this scenario? Currently there are two records having the same name, but the date_now fields contain `2015-12-11` and `2016-01-13` - I have a hard time to put this in the context "who paid this month, and who didn't" in any way, shape or form ;-) What problem do you want to solve: a) Didn't pay anthing in a given calendar month. b) Didn't pay anthing for over a month since last transaction. c) something else....(in case of c) please elaborate)

Comment: @VolkerK that's mean that the client paid for an item, and didn't paid for another, so the store shouldn't put him on the `Not Paid` List. That's it.

Comment: what I want is to put on `Not Paid` the people who didn't paid at all this month on all their bought items

Comment: Maybe I'm a little dumb today (certainly  feels that way; more coffee please) but how is `2015-12-11` and `2016-01-13` in the same month? It is not, even if you consider `'2015-12-11' + 1 month` instead of calendar months.

Comment: @VolkerK I assume all data from the query he gave qualifies for this check. Else we might have to come up with something more complex.

Comment: @Utsav any help or it is too complex